# MATLAB, como criar variáveis simbólicas com FOR?

Tags: matlab

como crio várias variáveis com o uso do for no matlab? Não estou conseguindo atrelar o índice do for com o nome que dou a variável por exemplo:

For i = 1:10

Syms Variável﻿ i; %o que eu boto aqui pra diferenciar ou pelo menos conseguir criar as variáveis como for?%
End

Obrigado!﻿

Answer (score 0):

Não entendi bem a ideia da sua aplicação mas por que no lugar de você criar várias variáveis apenas não declara um vetor como syms e na sequência utiliza do for para criar as n posições que você quer? Algo assim:

syms var
for i=1:10
    var(i) = i+3;
end
disp(var)

Answer (score -1):

A criação dinâmica de variáveis na versão R2019b, foi possível utilizando o comando *eval*, da seguinte forma:

```
for ii=1:10
    eval(['syms a',num2str(ii)])
end
```

Neste exemplo, foram criados 10 variáveis simbólicas de "a1, a2 ... a10".